# How to create a bundle programmatically in Cocoa?

Tags: cocoa, bundle, core-foundation

I tried to create a bundle like

```
CFBundleRef bundleRef = CFBundleCreate(kCFAllocatorDefault, (CFURLRef)@"/Users/MyUser/source/Mybundle.component");
```

but got SIGABRT

and

```
NSBundle* myBundle = [[NSBundle alloc]initWithPath:@"/Users/MyUser/source/Mybundle.component"];
```

but got nil. How can I do it properly? Should I create Mybundle.component directory before?

Comment: Why do you even think that you can cast an `NSString` to a `CFURLRef`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I tried to create a bundle like
>
> ```
> CFBundleRef bundleRef = CFBundleCreate(kCFAllocatorDefault, (CFURLRef)@"/Users/MyUser/source/Mybundle.component");
> ```
>
> but got SIGABRT

That's because a string is not a CFURL object. `CFBundleCreate` requires a URL object, and waving your hand and telling it “this is totally a CFURL object” is not enough to make that path into one. You need to actually create a CFURL or NSURL object and pass that there.

Make sure you use the proper function/method. For creating a URL from a path, in Cocoa, you want `fileURLWithPath:`, not `URLWithString:` (the latter expects a string representing a URL, not a path). CF has functions corresponding to each of these.

> and
>
> ```
> NSBundle* myBundle = [[NSBundle alloc]initWithPath:@"/Users/MyUser/source/Mybundle.component"];
> ```
>
> but got nil. … Should I create Mybundle.component directory before?

I wouldn't count on an empty directory being accepted as a bundle, but you do need a bundle to already exist at that path (or URL in CF) before you can create a bundle object for it.

If you're looking to create a bundle on disk from scratch programmatically, consider using [NSFileWrapper](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/ApplicationKit/Classes/NSFileWrapper_Class/).